# How to iterate through an array in an array?

Tags: java, json

I need to parse a JSON string in Java. I am using JSONObject to parse the string and get the object. I don't know how to loop through a triple array without knowing the keys.

This is the JSON as string:

```
{ "version": "0.8.0", "generator": "vzlogger", "data": [ { "uuid": "d495a390-f747-11e0-b3ca-f7890e45c7b2", "last": 0, "interval": -1, "protocol": "s0" }, { "uuid": "a76ffbb0-5fcb-11ec-afdd-597654871263", "last": 1639902960610, "interval": 0, "protocol": "d0", "tuples": [ [ 1639902960610, 33067 ] ] } ]
```

I need to loop through each data and get for each entry the uuid. And I need to get for each uuid the tuples. For example

```
uuid a76ffbb0-5fcb-11ec-afdd-597654871263 
first tuples 1639902960610 
second tuples 33067
...
```

In the array are 50 uuids, in the example above I have only copied the first.

This is my code:

```
JSONObject obj = http.getResponseJSON();
            
JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("data"); // notice that `"posts": [...]`

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++){
    String uuid = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("uuid");
    if (arr.getJSONObject(i).has("tuples")) {
        JSONArray tuples = arr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("tuples");
        log.println("UUID: "+uuid + "CNT: "+tuples.length());
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length(); j++){
            String tuple = tuples.getJSONObject(j).get ... HELP ... THERE IS NO KEY ....    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `getJSONArray(j)` instead of `getJSONObject(j)`?

Comment: And how can i get the value "1639902960610"? tuples.getJSONArray(j).get ....? I dont have a key, in json there is only a value defined

Comment: You use `getXXX(int)`, for example `getLong(0)` to get the first item in the array.

Answer (score 0):

You have nested array in tuples field. so first

1. traverse the outer array
2. then for every index, traverse the inner array and print the value directly.

Here is the working code

```java
            if (arr.getJSONObject(i).has("tuples")) {
                JSONArray outerTuples = arr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("tuples");
                System.out.println("UUID: " + uuid);
                for (int k = 0; k < outerTuples.length(); k++) {
                    JSONArray innerTuples = outerTuples.getJSONArray(k);
                    for (int j = 0; j < innerTuples.length(); j++) {
                        System.out.println(innerTuples.get(j));
                    }
                }
            }
```